# How should I call Vec::with_capacity with an i32?

Tags: rust

I have a function which allocates a vector on the stack. This code doesn't work:

```
fn my_func(n: i32) {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
}
```

The compiler says `n` needs to be a `usize`. I suppose that makes sense from a type safety point of view, but I need to use `n` in other calculations where an `i32` is called for. What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: FYI: The `Vec` struct (which consists of tree pointers/`usize`s) will be on the stack, but the `n * sizeof::<T>` buffer will always be on the heap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cast](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-cast-expressions) to usize.

```
let n: i32 = 4;
let v = Vec::<i16>::with_capacity(n as usize);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is this approach considered canonical in this situation?

Comment: The best approach would to be refactor the 'i32' into 'usize' if that is possible. Otherwise, I think this is your only option. Casting in Rust is unsafe so `-4` in `i32` will become a large positive `usize`  so you might want to do some testing on the values but that overhead could be unnecessary depending on your situation.

Comment: You can always use Numcast: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.NumCast.html#tymethod.from

Comment: At the very least I can make it a ``u32`` which should resolve most issues.

Comment: @DrYap, I believe that refactoring `i32` to `usize` is not the idiomatic approach. As far as I know, it is suggested that pointer-sized integers should be used as sparingly as possible, so the conversion to `usize` *is* the idiomatic approach. If you're converting from a sized type, you need to add a check that the number is indeed positive, though.

Comment: @DrYap A small niggle: casting in Rust is *safe*. It's true that casting `-4 as usize` will give you a large positive number, but this does not meet the very specific criteria that Rust uses to define "unsafe." (Which is a statement about memory safety.)